# How to use an anonomyous function directly to assign a value?

Tags: php, php-7, anonymous-function, php-7.3

I know I can do this:

```
 $myFunc = function () { return 42; };
 $val = $myFunc();
```

But I want to skip `$myFunc` and do something like this:

```
 $val = () { return 42; };
```

Is this possible?

Of course, my real function is more complicated. It looks like this:

```
function () use ($value) { 
             $a = $value['foo'] ?: ''; 
             $d = ['FOO' => 'F', 'BAR' => 'B', '' => ''];        
             return $d[$a];
         }
```

And I want to use it inside a dictionary, like:

```
$foobar = [
    'something' = function () use $(value) { ...
```

Am I onto something here? Or am I using the completely wrong approach? My alternatives, which I do not prefer is:

1. Declaring these functions as regular functions
2. Calculate the value before the dictionary and assign it later

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can wrap the function expression in parentheses and then immediately call it by appending `()`:

```
$val = (function () { return 42; })();
```